# Sql Decimal field size for latitude and longitude

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, google-maps

I want to save longitude and latitude in SQl server. I have two fields like

```
Latitude (decimal(18,10)) 
Longitude (decimal(18,10))
```

What can maximum value for fractional part for both. If I take it 10 it will save ten point after decimal, when I populate that point on map, I think it can effect if its not exact one.
e.g I have 76.992748 it will be saved as 76.9927480000 , here we go get extra four zero, I think it will effect location while populating it.

So basically I want to know maximum size for fractional part so can set fractional max range and want to save exact value no extra zero. Please help me I am using c# and SQl Server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you think there are differences?

Comment: Configsing. Someone needs to read what "10 point after the decimal" means.

Comment: I am not sure , may be I have not test it..

Comment: means Integer Value then fractional part eg 12.30 here 12 is integer and 30 is fractional part ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if that helps... have a look at Spatial data in Sql Server

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933876(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set actual value means you give datatype as float. Why you give the maximum  value in decimal point. The following blog is helpful for you analyze.

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/29/sql-server-difference-and-explanation-among-decimal-float-and-numeric/